# Painting without PaintEvent and QGraphicsItem s Management

Tags: qt, drawing, paint

The Scenario is I am getting Rects of Images over the socket and I need to draw it in a Scrollable Canvas. at the moment I am using a `QGraphicsScene` and drawing using `QGraphicsPixmapItem` but after few times when one pixmap overlaps another there is no need to keep the bottom one. and I dont know any simple way to find out the overlapped item and `delete` it. so its supposed to take huge memory if overlapping goes on like this.

there exists another way out. Make a `QWidget` and put it in a `QScrollArea` now draw the QWidget using a `QPainter` (outside paintEvent ?). If I draw it outside `paintEvent` I need to inherit the `QWidget` and make a custom one. pass it a Pixmap and let it draw in its own paintEvent by calling update()

Any critiques ? any other Straight forward solutions there ?